# Setting selected value of (Nth) element in a select box array in javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, select, dropdown

hope you guys can help, as I have tried and googled a few things, but I just cant get it right.

I have a select box array in a form.

```
<select name="travel_to[]" id="travel_to[]">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="travel_to[]" id="travel_to[]">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="travel_to[]" id="travel_to[]">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Each box can contain a different selected value from whatever options are populated in the boxes.. (but all the boxes contain the same options as each other) (which makes sense for what I want)

I would like to access the first select box from the "travel_to[]" array and set the selected value to "1"  then the second select box in the "travel_to[]"  array set the selected option value "2"  etc etc.

Any ideas?  I can parse the post of this using PHP, but setting a specifc select element from the array... im going around in circles..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers in advance :)

EDIT: 18/10/2018 at 10:00
Ok, have decided to do this differently.
Am going to make the ids be unique with an increment, by getting the total number of relevant input fields I have, and adding one more to the count, then keep the name being with the []

I thought I could do it having both name and id the same with the [], but way too much hassle, and doing this way with incremental ids.. should be easier..

Thanks all for those that responded.

Comment: This is invalid HTML. Duplicate of ids

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: @cid I dont think it is invalid as HTML and PHP seem to be parsing and coping with this perfectly when parsing and traversing and commiting the values to database.    Unless there is another way to make an input array  with a select / dropdown box.

Comment: @Jerodev  various versions of document.getElementById("travel_to[0]").options[1].selected=true


document.getElementById("travel_to")[0].options[1].selected=true


document.getElementById("travel_to[]")[0].options[1].selected=true


document.getElementById("travel_to").item[0].options[1].selected=true

but no luck I could be going about this in the wrong way, but to make an input array / collection ive always done it id="name[]"  etc and for what i have used it for so far.. works.. but setting certain select box in array.. no joy